# nested resources and build method for making association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have three models associated between: User, Post, Comment. Comment is nested resource with Post.

routes.rb

```
resources :posts do
 resources :comments
end
```

User model:

```
has_many :comments
```

Post model:

```
has_many :comments
```

Comment model:

```
belonsg_to :user
belonsg_to :post
```

The goal is when User makes new Comment it creates association with that user. So you can see it like User knows all comments he has made.

comments_controller.rb

```
def create
  @post = Post.find(params[post_id]
  @comment = @post.comments.build[:comment]
  current_user.comments >> @comment
  ....
end
```

new.html.erb

```
<% form_for [@post, @post.comment.build]  do |f| %>
.....
<% end %>
```

This gives me an error no method comments. What should I make to avoid this?

Comment: What's Prog model? and it's `belongs_to` not `belons_to`

Comment: Ref this link http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

Comment: You made a typo, could that be your problem? You wrote `<% form_for [@post, @post.comment.build]  do |f| %>` instead of `<% form_for [@post, @post.comments.build]  do |f| %>`. So `comments` instead of `comment`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you are missing "S" letter in new.html.erb. Should be comments:

```
<% form_for [@post, @post.comments.build]  do |f| %>
  .....
<% end %>
```

If there is some more logic behind you didn't post let us know. Your create action looks fine. Try to look in console student_id attribute, if its populated with ID than you are fine.cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
@post.comments.build
```

Instead of

```
@post.comment.build (x)
```

this should work, if possible move this line of code from view to controller

for more info
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#detailed-association-reference

Answer (score 0):

In **new.html.erb** file, you are using "s" for build method.

It should be,

```
<% form_for [@post, @post.comments.build]  do |f| %>
.....
<% end %>
```